# How to create a DataFrame series as a sub-string of a DataFrame Index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame which has a 5-digit string as its index (the index is a 5 digit zip code). I'd need to create another series in the DataFrame which is the first three characters of the index (i.e. the 3-Digit zip code).

As an example, if the index for a row is "32779", I'd like the new series' value to be "327".

I thought a Lambda function may work e.g.

```
fte5['Zip3'] = fte5.index.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x[:3])
```

But this gives an error

Answer (score 2):

The bracket operator on strings is exposed through `str.slice` function:

```
fte5.index.astype(str).str.slice(0,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
fte5['Zip3'] = fte5.index.get_level_values(0)
fte5['Zip3'] = fte5['Zip3'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x[:3])
```

Answer (score 0):

consider the `pd.DataFrame` `fte5`

```
fte5 = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((3, 2)), ['01234', '34567', '56789'], ['X', 'Y'])
fte5
```

[image]

If you already have 5 digit zipcodes that start with `0` then they must be `str` already.  The simplest way to get at the first 3 characters in a vectorized way is to use the `.str` string accessor rather than use `apply`.

```
fte5.index.str[:3]

Index(['012', '345', '567'], dtype='object')
```

We can assign it to `fte5['Zip3']` with `insert`

```
fte5.insert(2, 'Zip3', fte5.index[:3])
```